# Ubuntu server not appearing in Windows network after update to 22.04

Tags: networking, server, samba

I think I'd updated from Ubuntu 20.04, but there's a small possibility it was 18.04. Before the update the server appeared in my Windows network view just fine. I'm specifically using Win 7; but it's also not working on Win 10.

I can still access the server just fine. I have a startup script that mounts a Samba share, and that still works. And when I type the server address into the bar then it all opens as before.
What's not happening is when I just try to browse to it using the Network link in the left of Explorer. It used to appear along with the other computers in the top Computer section, as well as in the expandable list in the left nav bar. Now it just doesn't appear at all.

I figured it was Workgroup settings, but I checked those and it all seemed correct. I also found something about enabling some encryption settings in Windows, but that didn't fix it either (and to be honest I would have thought that would have affected general access too anyway).

Any ideas what else to check that the update to 22.04 might have changed/defaulted?

Comment: How did you do the upgrade? What commands?

Comment: @David `do-release-upgrade` after completing all available other updates from `dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version of Samba in Ubuntu 22.04 disables the SMB1 dialect and without that it cannot use NetBIOS for host discovery from it's clients.

You can enabled it yourself - but before you do that I would suggest you try something else. Install the protocol that Windows itself uses for discovery.

On your Ubuntu 22.04 machine install wsdd:

```
sudo apt install wsdd
```

Note: According to the documentation it should work with Win7:

> This daemon is used to announce Linux Hosts to Windows 7+ computers
> for use in their File Manager network browsing, by using the Windows
> Services Discovery Protocol.

It works very well with Win10/11 but I have not used it with Win7.

Should that not work you will have to enable SMB1 ( Samba calls it NT1 ) on your Ubuntu server by editing /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this one:

```
server min protocol = NT1
```

Samba likes to spawn serveral instances of smbd so your best bet is to just reboot the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Perfect, it appeared instantly when I installed wsdd! Thanks!