# Unable to access a Samba shared folder

Tags: networking, server, permissions, mount, samba

I've been trying to make a local backup of all my family's photos and videos for easy access due to how sluggish Dropbox has become. When I set up the Samba shared folder this showed up:

[image: Image displaying the message "Unable to mount Windows share: Permission denied"]

What's worse, it does not appear on the Windows Network. I've already tried install the Windows SMB1 feature in the Control Panel. The only way to access my desktop's file server on Windows is to type in the full IP address, but then when trying to access it on Windows it has the same error with this window popping up.

[image: Image displaying Windows being unable to open folder]

I am unsure what I have done wrong, as I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q0mnAT1MRg) step-by-step exactly how they said to do it.

Just in case someone else can spot what I did wrong with the files, here are my smb.conf file and shares.conf files.

smb.conf:

```
[global]
server string = Saturn Media Server
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
name resolve order = bcast host
include = /etc/samba/shares.conf
```

shares.conf:

```
[Public Files]
path = /media/saturn/4858443D58442C4E/Files/Public
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writable = no
```

Comment: You might want to see:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1438086/231142

Comment: @Terrance So, while this did fix the problem with the network not showing up on Windows (Nearly instantaneously!), I am still unable to access the folders on both computers

Comment: Try adding `usershare allow guests = yes` to the `[global]` section of your conf file.  You will have to restart Samba between any new settings `systemctl restart smbd.service`

Answer (score 0):

```
[Public Files]
path = /media/saturn/4858443D58442C4E/Files/Public
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writable = no
```

Is "saturn" a user name on this server?

If it is no one but "saturn" will be able to get to the shared folder.

I would change force user / group in your share definition from smbuser to saturn:

```
force user = saturn
force group = saturn
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

All future files created by the client will save with saturn as owner.